# Twitter API - Spring authentication error

Tags: java, spring, twitter, spring-social-twitter

**REST**
I also tried with the postman but it gives the same error
@RestController
@RequestMapping()
public class REST {

```
        @GetMapping("/tweet")
        public void noticiaPost(){
             String consumerKey = "AVlNWQzs3FYQ2DHsdDWY***";
              String consumerSecret = "UL1PCQzBxm9kkEVDte3dgbgzgT7A*******";
              
              String accessToken = "1281888984361308163-zqxjCD********";
              String accessTokenSecret = "hMwcViNClKKjDj1TH751*****";
              
              TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate = 
                     new TwitterTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
         
              twitterTemplate.timelineOperations().updateStatus("hola buenos dias");
        }
```

**application properties**
Aplication properties where i put consumekeys and accesstoken from twitter developer

```
   SpringAtSO.consumerKey=AVlNWQzs3FYQ*****
    SpringAtSO.consumerSecret=UL1PCQzBxm9kkEVDt*****
    SpringAtSO.accessToken=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALk2WILF6Wr*******
```

**ERROR**
i dont understand this, i put all the keys in restcontroller

```
2021-01-18 10:50:18.214  WARN 4396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.c.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  : Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: personalization_id="v1_wttGCbR3euCsc75cUIKYPQ=="; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Wed, 18 Jan 2023 09:50:17 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 09:50:17 GMT
2021-01-18 10:50:18.214  WARN 4396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.c.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  : Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A161096341741656047; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Wed, 18 Jan 2023 09:50:17 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 09:50:17 GMT
ERROR:   401 UNAUTHORIZED :: Could not authenticate you.
2021-01-18 10:50:18.240 ERROR 4396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.] with root cause

org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterErrorHandler.handleClientErrors(TwitterErrorHandler.java:100) ~[spring-social-twitter-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterErrorHandler.handleError(TwitterErrorHandler.java:60) ~[spring-social-twitter-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:714) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:440) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.updateStatus(TimelineTemplate.java:198) ~[spring-social-twitter-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.updateStatus(TimelineTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-social-twitter-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.Twitter.controller.REST.noticiaPost(REST.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: It looks like you’re using a Bearer Token in the `SpringAtSO.accessToken` variable, which means that the user is not authenticated. You do have what appears to be a user access token in the method itself, I don’t know if one is overriding the other inside the Spring template.

Comment: I tried to remove it, but it remains the same :(

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?